# What is this Nested For Loop doing? (Asterisk Right Triangle)

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I just started learning about "nested for loops". But my question what is the nested for loop exactly doing every time it loops? I'm still confused as to what is variable "i" is doing and what is variable "j" is doing. If you can explain what is happening after every loop, it would make nested for loops much clearer.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LoopStatement {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int numStar;

        System.out.print("Number of stars: ");
        numStar = input.nextInt();

        while (numStar < 1 && numStar > 20) {
            System.out.println("Enter a valid number ");
            numStar = input.nextInt();
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= numStar; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

So this is the output I get if I input **4** for **numStar**

```
*
**
***
****
```

Comment: Nested loops behave exactly the same way as un-nested loops. They run to completion before moving on in the code. With nested loops, "moving on" means going to the next iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: When i = 1, the inner loop is going from 1 to 1 (just one *)
When i = 2, the inner loop is going from 1 to 2 (two  *)
When i = 3, the inner loop is going from 1 to 3 (three *)
...

Answer (score 0):

There is actually nothing special about nested loops, they behave exactly the same like regular loop.

Specifically here the outer loop loops from `i` being `1` to `numStar` and therefore prints `numStar` rows.

The nested loop loops from `j` being `1` to `i` where `i` is the number of current row being printed. In each iteration it prints one star and therefore altogether it prints `i` stars.

Therefore here it prints `1` star on row number `1`, `2` stars on row number `2`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing down in a paper like this :

```
i=1  j=1 => *
i=1  j=2 => (j<=i) is false
.
.
i=2  j=1  => *
             *

i=2  j=2  => *
             **
.
.
```

You'll get the output if you try to write it in a paper.

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand the nested loop you must understand the for structure. It sounds like you did not get it.

from the basics:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numStar; i++) {
    System.out.println(i); 
}
```

the code above iterate exactly numStart following the steps:
a-Starts with i=1: `int i = 1`
b-Test condition: `i <= numStar`
c-Print the value of i in the screen: `System.out.println(i)`
d-increments i value: `i++`

It execute while the conditions is satisfied: `i <= numStar`. The steps c and d are executed only the condition is satisfied.

the tested loop follows the same logic:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numStar; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
       System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

when i=1 -> j iterates from 1 to 1. So it prints "*"

when i=2 -> j iterates from 1 to 2. So it prints "**"

when i=3 -> j iterates from 1 to 3. So it prints "***"

and so on...

After the nested iteration finish there is line break: `System.out.println();`